# Warning message after installing R

Tags: r

I have installed R many time in the last two decades. Today for the first time something went wrong.

After installing on a brand new laptop with windows 10 pro, I get this warning every time I open the program:

```
During startup - Warning message:
Setting LC_CTYPE= failed
```

I tried reading about this, but all I could find was MAC related, I have a lenovo thinkpad with windows 10.

Edit: Session Info

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sessioninfo_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1   assertthat_0.2.0 cli_1.0.1        tools_3.5.1      withr_2.1.2     
[6] rstudioapi_0.8   yaml_2.2.0       crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: What does session info say?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the session info

Comment: My locale looks something like that: `locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252, LC_CTYPE=....`

Comment: What does it mean ? Is it a windows problem ? Everything seems to be working fine despite this warning.

Comment: Stränge. I have really no idea...